# j2ee: I have a problem regarding jboss server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am using jboss 4.2 server and oracle xe both have same port  ie 8080 so I want to change my jBoss port  for run our application please tell me how to change port in jboss.
I know how to change port in tomcat but I didnot find in jboss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to change the 8080 port:

1. Goto the deploy folder of the server instance you use.
2. Goto the jbossweb-tomcat55.sar inside that deploy folder.
3. Find the file named server.xml inside that folder. (tomcat service file).
4. Look for the HTTP Connector section inside the server.xml where 8080 configuration is available. Change the port value to what ever the required port number.

(taken from [here](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2006/09/jboss-4-how-to-change-port-8080-in.html) , first result when googling it :-) )

See this question for changing all JBoss ports at once
[Running JBoss AS 5 and JBoss AS 4 simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592091/running-jboss-5-and-jboss-4-at-the-same-time)